# Jetty error when runnig gplus-quickstart

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jetty, war

I'm trying to run `gplus-quickstart-java` with `IntelliJ` and `Maven` but I have an error I don't understand. If you could tell me what I did wrong, it'd be great.

I've created an empty Maven Project, downloaded the project's source from google+ platform,copied the Signin.java, etc...and modified the pom.xml file to this (I took off the headers):

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev120-1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.t7mp</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-t7-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I try to run, the **error** I get is:

> 2014-03-20 09:52:48.030::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
>   2014-03-20 09:52:48.066::INFO:  jetty-7.0.0.pre5
>   2014-03-20 09:52:48.125::WARN:  failed org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager@12221f6
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.doStart(AbstractSessionManager.java:170)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.doStart(HashSessionManager.java:71)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:115)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin.main(Signin.java:123)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   2014-03-20 09:52:48.144::WARN:  failed SessionHandler@18fee4f
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.doStart(AbstractSessionManager.java:170)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.doStart(HashSessionManager.java:71)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:115)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin.main(Signin.java:123)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   2014-03-20 09:52:48.144::WARN:  Error starting handlers
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.doStart(AbstractSessionManager.java:170)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.doStart(HashSessionManager.java:71)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:115)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
>       at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>       at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.Signin.main(Signin.java:123)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   2014-03-20 09:52:48.162::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4567

Waiting for your solutions (thx). Ask if there's an info I should have given.